# The Russian-American Company in Valparaíso

Tags: russia, trade, age-of-sail, chile

The [Russian-American Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian-American_Company) bought a lot of grain in Spanish and Mexican California. In 1829 or 1830, not enough was available, and the ship Baikal under captain Etholén continued south to Chile. Kirill Khlebnikov was aboard, probably as supercargo. According to Winston Sarafian, some company employees deserted in Valparaíso.

What news or impressions did the Russians make?

Comment: Might have been the first *Russian-American* ship, but not the first [Russian ship](https://www.wdl.org/en/item/19544/).

Comment: Do you have any more specific information from this source concerning the date? I have found information on the Baikal, but she is usually listed as a Brig. Etolin was in Valparasio, but much later than 1830, more near when he takes over as manager of RAC(1840).

Comment: I see conflicting information on what kind of ship Baikal was so I removed that detail. My sources here are Pierce's _Builders of Alaska: The Russian Governors 1818-1867_ and Sarafian's _Russian-American Company employee policies and practices_. Maybe there were multiple trips to Chile?

Comment: Pierce says on different pages that the ship returned to Sitka 1830/3/15 and 1830/5/15.

Comment: The Baikal is also listed in the notes in Bancroft as well, but no mention of her heading south (of course the list is just ships off Cal., so where it went was off-topic, or unknown).

Comment: @AaronBrick: What's a "supercargo"?

Comment: @gktscrk A [supercargo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercargo) is responsible for the disposition of the cargo on the ship, often employed directly by the corporation or backers of the ships voyage. He may make the actual transactions when the ship goes to port, buying or selling as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These Russians probably weren't big news: numerous Russian voyages had already stopped in Chile. By 1827 Talcahuano was "a resting-place indicated in the Admiralty instructions". N. A. Ivashintsov in *Russian Round-the-World Voyages, 1803-1849* indicates that:

- the *Rurik* spent a month at Talcahuano in 1816
- the *Predpriiatie* spent six weeks at Talcahuano in 1824
- the *Krotkii* spent ten days at Valparaiso in 1827
- the *Moller* spent two weeks at Valparaiso in 1827
- the *Seniavin* spent two weeks at Valparaiso in 1827